# Literature on the PDE $\partial_t f + \partial_x(f(1-f))=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, transport-equation

I am looking for literature on this variant of the transport PDE:

$$\partial_t f + \partial_x(f(1-f))=0.$$

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special case of a [conservation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law#Exact_laws) that can be (and has been) written in [divergence form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_form)
$$ \partial_t f + \partial_x F(f) = 0$$
where $F(x) = x(1-x)$. You can find some information about this class of equations in e.g. Evans' *Partial Differential Equations*, Chapter 3.4. IMO, a softer introduction can be found in Alinhac's book *Hyperbolic Partial Differential Equations*, Chapter 4. One small point, the theory at some points assumes $F$ is convex, or even uniformly convex, which we can achieve by setting $u = -f$ so that we have the equation
$$ u_t + G(u)_x = 0,\quad G(x) = x(x+1)$$